# Find the minimal value of $\frac{x(x-1)+y(y-1)}{2}-xy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, discrete-mathematics, optimization

I need to find the minimal value of $f(x, y) = \frac{x(x-1)+y(y-1)}{2}-xy$ where $x$ and $y$ are both positive integers. I tried to find the minimum with the help of derivatives:

1) With respect to x: $ f'(x, y) = x - y - \frac{1}{2}$

2) With respect to y: $ f'(x, y) = y - x - \frac{1}{2}$

I have read that the extremal points of function of two variables can be found if we set both derivatives(with respect to x and y) to 0, but this cannot happen since their sum is always $-1$. Could somebody help me to find the minimum(might be without calculus?)

EDIT: From the comments below it seems that this function doesn't have a global minimum. So I want to change the statement as follows: find the minimum of $f(x, y)$ where $x + y = n$

Comment: There is no global minimum

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: Note that $f(a,a)=-a$.

Comment: If there was a minimum then $\nabla f$ would be 0 there.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that I have missed something (almost) obvious. And I have another question: if we know that $x+y=n$, what is the minimum of $f(x, y)$ in terms of $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to minimize $$f = \frac{x(x-1)+y(y-1)}{2}-xy$$ under the constraint $x+y=k$, substitute $y=k-x$ in the expression. This gives $$f=2 x^2-2 k x+\frac{k(k-1)}{2} $$ Taking derivative $$f'=4x-2k$$ and since you want $f'=0$, this leads to $x=y=\frac k 2$ and the minimum value of $f$ is then $-\frac k 2$. The second derivative test ($f''=4$) confirms that this is the minimum. For sure, now the problem is that you want that $k$ be an integer; I leave that to you.

Answer (score 6):

Your function is $\frac 12\big((x-y)^2-x-y\big)=\frac 12 \big((x-y)^2-n\big)$ post edit. To minimize set $x=y$.